# WPF: Any reason why there's a xamlparse exception on XP but not on Vista?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

My app compiles fine. Runs fine on Vista machines. But doesn't even start on XP machines with a xaml parse exception on the first form.

The xp machines all have .net 3.5.

Anything spring to mind?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the exception and how you deployed the application?

Comment: Perhaps the app was developped with 3.5 SP1, and the XP machines only have 3.5 ?

Comment: Have you found what's causing it? I met with the exact same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exception could mean pretty much anything.

If you do as described in [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809032534/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx) (it's not much, just a try/catch and get the inner exception out) you should be able to see more details and hopefully find the cause of the exception (which could be trivial).

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The XAML parse exception is the outer exception that gets called when the form is instantiating all of its child elements. It's probably being thrown because one of these child elements is throwing another exception during instantiation. You need to check the InnerException property of the xamlparse exception, the InnerException of the InnerException, etc until you find the root exception that's causing the problem.

My first guess would be a missing service pack, but the only way to know for sure is to find the root exception.